# why does unserialize keep returning false even after using stripslashes

Tags: php, serialization

$question_data contains this string `string(163) "a:5:{s:7:"form_id";s:1:"4";s:5:"title";s:7:"Aurelie";s:9:"text_area";s:22:"dfgdfsgfdgfdgfdgdfgfdg";s:7:"options";s:10:"First Name";s:6:"degree";s:11:"Bachelor's";}"`

unserialize($question_data) keeps returning false

Comment: It indicates the binary representation got butchered along the way. Your mention of stripslashes also hints at inproper handling. And there's not much more anyone can tell without a binary dump and/or suitable code excerpts.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is with `s:11:"Bachelor's";`

The string is declared as being 11 characters in length, but you only have 10 there. I suspect the original data was `s:11:"Bachelor\\'s";` and somehow the backslash got eliminated altogether.